# Why is it that I can't use == in a For loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I don't know if that's been asked before, but I haven't been able to find an answer, nonetheless. My question is this; in For loops, this is acceptable.

```
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    k++;
```

But this is NOT:

```
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i == 10; i++)
    k++;
```

Why is it that I cannot use '==' to determine whether the condition has been met? I mean, both expressions return true or false depending on the situation and the latter would be appropriate for, say, an If loop.

```
int k = 10;

if (k == 10)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

The answer to this question has been bothering me for a good while now during my time as a hobbyist programmer, but I hadn't searched for it till now.

Comment: A for loop runs **while** the condition is true...

Comment: OK, that cleared everything up for me. How come I didn't think of that? Hence the `while` loop alternative.

Comment: You can use `==` but you can iterate max one time.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That's a legitimate answer to a legitimate question.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: That would depend on what you put in the increment statement.... a no-op would run forever.

Comment: Here's a `for` loop with `==` used in a different way: `for (var dateTime = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1); dateTime.Year == 2014; dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1.0)) { Console.WriteLine(dateTime); }`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `for` loop will run while the condition is satisfied. At the beginning `i = 0`, so your test `i == 10` is never satisfied and thus the body of the loop is never executed.

On the other hand you could have used `i == 0` condition and the loop would have executed only once:

```
for (int i = 0; i == 0; i++)
    k++;
```

That's the reason why if you want a for loop to execute more than once, you need to provide a condition for the iterator variable that is `<` or `>` so that it can be satisfied more than once while this iterator variable increments/decrements.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to mention `for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++)` as well?

Answer (score 7):

For loop works until the condition is true so you can write

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
k++;
```

Comment: You mean a `for` loop executes as long as the condition is true, but the example with `!=` is helpful.

Answer (score 6):

When you put i==10 then it checks for condition for i whether it equals to 10 or not. and obviously i =0 at initial stage, so loop breaks out

so if you want to break loop at some condition then preferably you should use

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    if(i==5) // test with your condition
    break;
    k++;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely **can** write such a condition.

It just wouldn't make much sense.

Here's the broken down syntax of the `for` loop:

`for(<initial statement>;<boolean expression - keep going while true>;<statement performed after each iteration>)`

So in the typical scenario you described

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    k++;
```

the initial statement is a declaration of `i`. The loop will run for as long as **`i` remains 10 or less**, and after each iteration `i` will be incremented by one.

To summarize - you totally can write `i == 10`, it's just that it wouldn't make much sense because the loop wouldn't run, as `i` is already 0. If you had replaced the initial condition with `int i = 10` then it would be run only once. You could have also written `i != 10` as the condition, and then the loop would execute 10 times.

Answer (score -1):

In the second part of the "FOR" equation a condition must be met for the loop to work - the condition must be True.

But if the condition is not fulfilled it becomes a False, so The loop will not be executed.

So variable (i) cannot be equal to zero in the first section of "FOR"

Then you write in the second section in “FOR”, which is responsible for executing the loop. The question is about the condition that the variable (i) must be equal to ten in order to execute the loop. Of course, the loop will not be executed.

But any of these signs  < , ! , =
can be use with the number until the condition becomes True.

for Example:

```
i <=10
```

or

```
i <11
```

or

```
i !=11
```

Because one of them will be True then the condition is True

But you can't use > operator because (i) = 0
So any number after > bigger than 0 will cause of the condition will be False and the the loop will be terminated.

Here how the loop will work from Start to the End

Note:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
  k++;
```

Loop reading order

1. int i = 0
2. i <= 10
3. k++
4. i++

The order of reading the loop in the first cycle

```
FOR ( 1 ; 2 ; 4)
  {3}
```

The order of the Loop reading from the second cycle

```
FOR ( - ; 5 ; 7 )
  {6}
```

And so on as long as the condition is met and is True

The order of the Loop reading from the third cycle to the penultimate

```
FOR ( - ; 8 ; 10 )
  {9}
```

And so on as long as the condition is met and is True

The order of the Loop reading in the last cycle

```
FOR ( - ; 11 ; - )
  { - }
```

If you notice that it will be read only the condition and if it False the loop will be terminated without reading the others.

Also note this:

In your equation you can change this

```
from :   int k = 0; 
to   :   int k = 10;
```

and using your equation  without change

```
for (int i = 0; i == 10; i++)
  k++;
```

But it will work only for one cycle and K will be = 1 and the loop will be terminated.